# Multi-threading with Class and without class in python using join

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, join

I am practicing in python multithreaded environment for my project. I have developed(probably copied :)) a sample program which will use thread join method so main thread will wait till other threads finish, using threading model.

```
import threading
import time


class MyThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = thread_id
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        threadLock.acquire()
        print_time(self.name, self.counter, 3)
        # Free lock to release next thread
        threadLock.release()


def print_time(thread_name, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s" % (thread_name, time.ctime(time.time()))
        counter -= 1

threadLock = threading.Lock()

thread1 = MyThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = MyThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print 'waiting to finish the thread'

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

output of the above :

```
Starting Thread-1
waiting to finish the threadStarting Thread-2

Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:31:04 2014
Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:31:05 2014
Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:31:06 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:31:08 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:31:10 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:31:12 2014
Exiting Main Thread

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I comment these lines of join method

```
#thread1.join()
#thread2.join()
```

Then I get the output as

```
Starting Thread-1
waiting to finish the threadStarting Thread-2

Exiting Main Thread
Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:32:31 2014
Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:32:32 2014
Thread-1: Tue Nov 18 16:32:33 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:32:35 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:32:37 2014
Thread-2: Tue Nov 18 16:32:39 2014

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### **Which is expected**

Now I have written one more code as

```
import time
import threading


def printer():
    for _ in range(5):
        print 'Hello'
        time.sleep(1)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printer())
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=printer())
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=printer())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
print 'Bye Bye'
```

For this I have not used `join()` method of threads, But I am getting output as

```
Hello
Hello
:
Hello
:
Hello
:
Hello
Bye Bye

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And with using `join()` also I am getting same output.

As per my understanding of threads and joins, when I haven't used the `join()` statement `'Bye Bye'` should be printed in the middle somewhere and not at the last.

Is there any behavior which changes for classes and simple functions in python?

Comment: From where does `Process finished with exit code 0` and `Exiting Main Thread` come?

Comment: Exiting Main thread- I had print statements in code. Process finished...., python code returns 0 when program run succesfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target` should be a function, not the result of a function (unless that result is a function). eg. `target=printer`. Note the absence of brackets.

What you have effectively done is run `printer` three times. Then started three threads which have nothing to do. Then printed bye bye.

Comment: result of function when I use brackets.. Would you please elaborate that?

Comment: When you write `printer()` you call the function then and there. When you write `target=printer()` you call printer and set target as the return value (`None` in this case). What you want to do is a give a function for the thread object to call when it runs.

Comment: Thanks Dunes for clarification